Taking only a four-digit number as user input
In a shell script, I'm reading user input into a variable. Before I can do anything with it, I need to confirm if the input is a 4-digit number. If not, I want to exit the program without doing anything.
read num

if [ #num is a 4-digit number ]
then
    #do something
fi

I'm a shell script beginner and also do not know how to work with regular expressions. I just need to check if the input is a 4-digit number using any way that works.

Can it start with one or more zeroes?

Some shells don't understand regular expressions (though they understand ordinary shell patterns).  What shell specifically are you working with?

@RomeoNinov Yes. It can.

@Kusalananda I'm not sure. The archetype is unix basic and I'm working in an online, hosted IDE.

Most shells have builtin support for glob pattern matching, few have builtin support for regular expression pattern matching.
With standard sh syntax, using glob pattern matching via the case construct:
#! /bin/sh -
while true; do
  printf>&2 'Please enter a 4 decimal digit number: ' || exit
  IFS= read -r number || exit
  case $number in
    ([0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]) break
  esac
  printf>&2 'Incorrect, please try again.\n' || exit
done
echo "Doing something with $number"

For a perl-like regexp match, you can use zsh:
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o rematchpcre
until
  IFS= read -r 'number?Please enter a 4 decimal digit number: ' || exit
  [[ $number =~ '^\d{4}\z' ]] 
do
  print -u2 'Incorrect, please try again.' || exit
done
print Doing something with $number

zsh can also prompt with a more user-friendly line editor than the one that comes with the terminal device driver with its vared variable editor builtin, and can also do the input validation upon pressing enter and not accept the value then for the user to get the option to edit it:
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
accept-line() {
  if [[ $BUFFER = [0-9](#c4) ]]; then
    zle .$WIDGET
  else
    zle -R "Invalid number."
    sleep 1
    return 1
  fi
}
zle -N accept-line
number=
vared -p 'Please enter a 4 decimal digit number: ' number
print Doing something with $number

Here also showing an alternative way to match 4 decimal digits with zsh extendedglobs.

The zsh-based solution works for me. Thanks a ton.
